# java.net.ConnectException: Invalid argument (connect failed)error

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, refactoring, apache-httpclient-4.x

I had a working REST library consisting of some interfaces and corresponding implementation.

I segregated those interfaces in an API maven project, then implementations in IMPL maven project because of some reasons.

Then corresponding import change in other consuming projects.

To mention, there is no change in code and all, changes are only in the imports and maven packaging (splitting in API and IMPL).

After this, my integration tests are failing as my library is failing with the below exception:

```
rg.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 10.216.239.136:13443 [/10.216.239.136] failed: Invalid argument (connect failed)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
        at my----some--package--impl.HttpSecureSenderImpl.invokeSecureInternal(HttpSecureSenderImpl.java:522)
        at my----some--package--impl.HttpSecureSenderImpl.invokeSecure(HttpSecureSenderImpl.java:448)
        at my----some--package--impl.RestClientImpl$RestCallable.call(RestClientImpl.java:589)
        at  my----some--package--impl.RestClientImpl$RestCallable.call(RestClientImpl.java:444)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Invalid argument (connect failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
```

I tried finding the reason, but seems after native call to `socketConnect` in `PlainSocketImpl`. I cannot proceed.

Any suggested way to move forward to identify and resolve the issue?
Why does this "invalid argument" comes at all?

Comment: Did you try to debug it? `/10.216.239.136` does not look as an http URL.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of the code that is raising this exception?

Comment: Yes I debugged it.and it goes till plain socket impl and then to native call and then invalid argument  error.the problem only occurs once I pull interfaces as another maven articact and keep implementation  as a separate maven artifact and whole packaging  package both api and implementation as in my final osgi package.....giving minimal working will be having lots of osgi specific dependencies and to test it will be needing karaf container

Comment: I have not at all do

Comment: Have not done any logical change except packaging.so not sure if slash thing shall be pointer or not.need to know why invalid argument comes.